# how to iterate on timestamp with given frequency in python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a reference date: Timestamp('1992-10-01 00:00:00') and frequency with 'MS'. I am trying to iterate around this reference date with given frequency.

Example1:

```
Timestamp('1992-10-01 00:00:00') with 1-'MS' back: Timestamp('1992-09-01 00:00:00')
```

Example2:

```
Timestamp('1992-10-01 00:00:00') with 2'MS' after: Timestamp('1992-12-01 00:00:00')
```

Is there any pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If using a monthly frequency (which is not a fixed frequency), you're better to convert to Periods.  eg

```
pd.Period(pd.Timestamp("1992-10-01"), freq="M") - 1
```

gives you

```
Period('1992-09', 'M')
```

Periods have a `.to_timestamp()` function if you need to convert back

You may also find `pandas.date_range` handy, eg

```
pd.date_range("1992-10-01", freq="MS", periods=5)
```

or the Period equivalent `pandas.period_range`

Comment: I used pd.Period with "MS" and unfortunately it gives an error. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: "MS" is the problem - it's just "M" with Periods